# Preloading large images after page has finished loading

Tags: javascript, image, onload, preloading

I found this bit of code and it works great for preloading, but it totally clogs the page load initially. I've been trying for hours to get this thing to run only after the page is loaded with no success. I've been using one image, "big_image.jpg" (8MB) to test it out. As is, everything preloads using the below code, including the large file. Anytime I attempt to get it to pre-load after the document is ready, it fails. I've even tried other code that purports to do what I want, but they all fail - once the page loads, none will keep loading the really big image. Whats up with that?

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
this.each(function(){
    $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
});
}

// Usage:

$(['picture.jpg','background.jpg','vertical.jpg','big_image.jpg']).preload();
```

Comment: Please clarify your question?

Comment: Can you show us your code in jsfiddle.net or codepen.io? 
It seems that you are using jQuery. You can wrap the function call inside a [ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: I just wrapped in the ready function and it's loading the big image, the only issue I have is that it's holding up a scrollbar script that is placed at the bottom of the page. Below is the script:

<script>
    (function($){
        $(window).load(function(){
            $("#story").mCustomScrollbar();

   $("#minigallery").mCustomScrollbar();  
  
        });
    })(jQuery);

</script>

I have the image preloading in a separate javascript file that is linked in the header.

Comment: Thanks for the help! You got me searching threw the jquery events and I set the scroll bar from $(window).load to $(document).ready - It seems to be working the way I need it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you found the answer based on my help:

It seems that you are using jQuery. You can wrap the function call inside a [ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
function loadImages(){     
  var img1 = "http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2826/11581275325_d61be12908_h.jpg"
  var markup = "<h3>Images after pageload</h2>"+"<img src='"+img1+"' />";
  $("#images").html(markup);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  loadImages();
});
```

You may take a look at my [codepan example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dbAJK)